# Yum install mod_passenger fails with [Errno 14] curl#35 - "TCP connection reset by peer"

Tags: passenger, yum

I am trying to follow the Phusion Passenger [installation instructions for CentOS/RHEL 7](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/apache/install/oss/el7/). I am encountering a problem with the HTTPS connection to the Passenger repo.

I was able to solve it for the `curl` request to get the repository definition by adding `--tlsv1` to the request to force TLSv1. However, I haven't been able to do the same for `yum`, as it is still failing with the following message:

```
failure: repodata/repomd.xml from passenger: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/yum/passenger/el/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml:
[Errno 14] curl#35 - "TCP connection reset by peer"
```

I have tried adding a `.curlrc` file with `tlsv1`, but `yum` doesn't appear to read that file, and continues to fail with the same error.

1. Is it possible to configure `yum` to always use TLSv1?
2. Are there public URLs for the RPM packages that I could download and install using `curl` and `rpm`, and bypass `yum` altogether?
3. Phusion Passenger devs, is there something on your repository server that could be changed to allow `yum` to connect? I am on CentOS 7.0.1406 with `yum` 3.4.3.

**Updated:** `curl -V` returns:

```
curl 7.29.0 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.29.0 NSS/3.28.4 zlib/1.2.7 libidn/1.28 libssh2/1.4.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz unix-sockets
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to have been an outdated `nss` package. Updating the `nss` package worked:

```
sudo yum install nss
```

After that, I was able to download the yum repo definition with `curl`, and install the `mod_passenger` package with `yum`.

Answer (score 0):

Phusion just fixed an issue with that server, can you try again now?

Comment: No. The only thing that might be odd is this is running on a Vagrant box. But previously it was working fine.

Comment: Yes, both of those exist, although `ca-bundle.crt` is a symlink to `tls-ca-bundle.pem`.

Comment: I just tried updating my CA certs by running `sudo yum install ca-certificates`. There was an update (`yum list installed` now returns `ca-certificates.noarch 2017.2.14-71.el7`), but that did not change anything when I try to download the passenger repo definition or install the mod_passenger package.

Comment: The VM looks like it is no more than 2 seconds behind the host. I ran `vagrant ssh -- date && date` and got `Wed Oct 18 16:54:06 UTC 2017` followe dby `Wed Oct 18 12:54:08 EDT 2017`

Comment: Plus, I just installed and started NTP, but I am still getting the error. Are you sure it is a cert problem, and not a SSL/TLS protocol problem? Is the `oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com` set up to be particularly strict about the SSL/TLS version or cipher suite it accepts?

Comment: Can you try again now?

Comment: I tried again, from a fresh Vagrant VM, but I get the same error when connecting to `oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com`.

* About to connect() to oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com port 443 (#0)  
*   Trying 109.107.35.58...  
* Connected to oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com (109.107.35.58) port 443 (#0)  
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb  
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt  
CApath: none  
* NSS error -5961 (PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR)  
* TCP connection reset by peer  
* Closing connection 0  
curl: (35) TCP connection reset by peer

Comment: I think I finally figured out what I needed to do (hat tip to  https://superuser.com/q/916077 for reminding me to try debugging the connection with `openssl s_client`). I updated the `nss` package, and now I can download the repo definition and the packages.

Comment: Really? I used the same NSS package that your curl reported (NSS/3.28.4) and was able to connect. Oh well, be sure to create an answer and mark it as correct.